# Why simulator shows the exact number of nodes, while on a device is twice in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, nodes

I would like to know the reason that testing a game on a simulator give the exact number of created nodes but when running the same game on a device , the number of nodes go twice ?

Comment: You may try to add more info, eg. which Xcode you use... Also a minimal code required to reproduce the issue is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

By default Xcode shows Created nodes, and FPS on the bottom right of your screen. As for the exact node count it should be the exact same between Simulator/Device as it is the same thing. It may be something in your code. If you are looking to turn this off you can go into your `GameViewController.swift` and go into the `viewDidLoad` function and set `view.showFPS = false`

Comment: Thank you. I knew that but my question is different, when the node appear on the screen on a device, it comes 2 nodes.

Comment: This doesn't really answers the question.